# how to specify height and width of flex alert box in css?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In my Flex 4 app I would like all my alert boxes to be a specific width and height, how do I specify that in the CSS? I want to avoid having to specify the width and height every time I want to show an alert, that's why I'd like to set it in the CSS, but does not look like there's a way to..
Something like this does not work:

```
mx|Alert
{
  height: 100;
  width: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it Using Style + Code like this

Define **Style Properties** as

```
Alert {

        height:300;
        weight:300;
    }
```

Note: **height** and **weight** are **not** default style of **Alert**

Using them in **Code** as

```
var alert:Alert = Alert.show("Hello World");
alert.explicitHeight = Number(alert.getStyle("height"));
alert.explicitWidth = Number(alert.getStyle("weight"));
```

Working example of Flex3 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
    creationComplete="{show()}">
    <mx:Style>
        Alert {

            height:300;
            weight:300;
        }
    </mx:Style>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private function show():void
            {
                var alert:Alert = Alert.show("Hello World");
                alert.explicitHeight = Number(alert.getStyle("height"));
                alert.explicitWidth = Number(alert.getStyle("weight"));
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Explanation

Since **Alert** Control by default **not** support **height** and **weight** *style*, so example used them just for **holding** user defined **values** as variable.

In routine to display *Alert/Popup* on screen **Static** method **show** of class **Alert** is used, which returns the **instance/object** of **created/active** Alert/Popup, using this refrence its properties can be manipulated at runtime as done in above example i.e. **explicitHeight** and **explicitWidth**.

Hopes that Help

Answer (score 0):

CSS can only be used to set Style properties of components.  There are no dimension based style properties for the mx:Alert as you can see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html#commonstyleSummary) - although there is one to adjust the height of the header named 'headerHeight'.

You could try extending the mx:Alert class and giving it new style properties that would allow you to change the dimensions via CSS. Or you could extend the class and give it default dimensions in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it out of the box, but you could do it by extending your Alert and adding your own logic in the `updateDisplayList` to check for the style and change the property appropriately.

Generally not recommended however.  Just use the properties given to you instead.