# Change the alert box height and width?

Tags: javascript, html

**Its possible to change alert box height and width?**

Comment: Use this custom alert box javascript here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28812/Custom-Alert-Boxes-using-JavaScript-and-the-DOM

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible in **javascript** You can change the alert box style although but
You will have to add custom **jqueries** in this one but it will called popup not alert box

Checkout this link
[how to specify height and width of flex alert box in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706898/how-to-specify-height-and-width-of-flex-alert-box-in-css)

Comment: Kindly tell me how to add custom jqueries?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28812/Custom-Alert-Boxes-using-JavaScript-and-the-DOM Checkout this link

Comment: Alert box are in a absolute position what are you talking about you don't aware that absolute position is already responsive?

Comment: but it not responsive in chrome browser?

Comment: Hello talking about absolute position alert does not need that pls use popup make custom css for this one